# "Just My Code" in Chrome JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, web-inspector

Is there a way to force Chrome's debugger to skip specific source files or functions when stepping through code?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Can't you just select the `.js` files and place breakpoints on them?

Comment: Click "step over" when you run into one you want to avoid?

Comment: @pixelbobby: Some situations call for stepping through the code line by line because you're trying to debug the control flow and don't know in advance which breakpoints will be hit.
@Jeremy: Yes, you can step over manually, but if your code has a lot of low-level library calls, it would be much more convenient for this to happen automatically.

Comment: Do you have this _"Just My Code"_ feature in another IDE?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Visual Studio has had this feature for a while -- it can skip system libraries, as well sections of user code explicitly marked as hidden: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now available in Chrome Developer Tools as the "Framework blackboxing" feature: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing

Updated link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#blackbox

Comment: Updated link : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

Answer (score 2):

For those who are debugging via the Chrome Debugging extension in VS Code, you can add to the `skipfiles` section of your `launch.json`. Here's mine:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/**",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 9222,
            "skipFiles": [
              "node_modules/**/*.js",
              "runtime.js",
              "polyfills.js",
              "vendor.js",
              "analytics.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```